# REST API: how should a POSTing client learn about associated ids?

Tags: rest, api-design, json-api

I'm updating a RESTful API and it's already using JSON API.

I want to enable POSTs to `/quotes`, but quotes are required to have a `product`.

My question is: how should the client know about, and identify, the product that should be associated with the quote?

Here are a few ideas; I welcome others.

1. Require the client to GET `/products` first, find the desired product in the list returned, then send the `id` of the product in question.
2. Standardize some public list of codes that will never change, such that the client can simply trust that the code is reliable. E.g. if the product is Product 1 from Acme, the code could be `"acme_1"`, etc.

As for option 2, the code could either be sent in as an `attribute` or as a `relationship`. That is, we could either do

```
// option 2a
"data": {
  "type": "accounts",
  "attributes": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "product_code": "acme_1"
  }
}

// option 2b
"data": {
  "type": "accounts",
  "attributes": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
  relationships: {
    "type": "products",
    "id": "acme_1"
  }
}
```

Please send thoughts, suggestions, and/or reading suggestions!

Comment: I would go with the first option. It may be harder for clients but it scales better and is more reliable. Also, probably the client already fetched the product details to show on the UI on the same screen where he enters the quote (doesn't it?), so it would just be a matter of sending the correct product id in the quotes payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a one-to-many relationship between `quote` and `product` this should be reflected in your payload. A relationship must be in [`relationships`](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships) key of a resource object. A [`resource linkage`](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) must be under `data` key of a `relationships object`. Therefore both of your options presented as 2a and 2b are not compliant with spec. A valid payload to create a resource having a relationship would look like the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "accounts",
    "attributes": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
    relationships: {
      "product": {
        "data": {
          "type": "products",
          "id": "acme_1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that the example shows a relationship object for a one-to relationship. If an *account* could have many *product* `data` property of 
relationship object must be an array:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "accounts",
    "attributes": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
    relationships: {
      "product": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "products",
            "id": "acme_1"
          },
          {
            "type": "products",
            "id": "acme_2"
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From perspective of JSON API spec it does not matter how the client knows which ID to associate. The [spec only states](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-identification) that an `id` must be a string and that the combination of `type` and `id` "must identify a single, unique resource".

Of course the client must know to which resource should be associated with the created one. It's totally up to the application how to implement that one. It could be hard coded or fetched from the backend. For scalability and maintainability reasons I would recommend not to hard code it if there is any chance that it's changing on a regular basis. But from JSON API spec perspective it only matters if the referenced related resource exists. Otherwise the server [must return a `404 Not Found`](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating-responses-404).

Comment: JSON API is extremely convoluted though. The same thing can be expressed as: `products: ['acme1', 'acme2']`.

Comment: JSON API is meant to not only support the simple cases. E.g. what you are suggesting would not support polymorphic relationships.

Comment: If that requirement exists, that might be a good time to rethink it. It's silly to make such a premature optimization at the start.